# How to remove English words from a file containing Dari words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, nlp, stanford-nlp

How to find English words and remove them from the file which contains Dari words? I tried this code, but I do not know how to improve it.

```
inp = open('Dari.pos', 'r')
out = open('DariNER.txt', 'w')

for line in iter(inp):
   ------------?
   out.write(word)
inp.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you struggle?

Comment: @UniversE I only read the file and list all English and non-English words, but I dont know how to detect English word and to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You could install and use the `nltk` library. This provides you with a list of English words and a means to split each line into words:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import words

english = words.words()

with open('Dari.pos') as f_input, open('DariNER.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        f_output.write(' '.join(word for word in word_tokenize(line) if word.lower() not in english) + '\n')
```

After installing nltk, you should run:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

and use it to download `words`

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = "Dari.pos"
outfile = "Cleaned_English_Tags.txt"

delete_list = ['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'PUNCT', 'INTJ', 'ADV', 'VERB', 'X', 'CCONJ', 'ADP', 'AUX', 'SCONJ', 'PRON', 'DET', 'NUM', 'AU']
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, 'w')

for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, " ")
    fout.write(line)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```